# how to get the similar city

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

i have a city `ALMA` but it can be more then 5 in the whole world so user can be confused. how i can show the all place who have a word `ALMA` in their location.

i want to get all city name who have word `ALMA`. are any api can give me all city , county name match to my name `ALMA`.

if i can use GMAP API [google] then how i  can retrieve all city name who have word "`ALMA`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at Yahoo PlaceFinder API ... That should help you out. If you suffix a near by location to the city name as in district etc it will help you drill down to the one you want.
http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Comment: if user live in alma canada then canada ownself have 6 location but if user want to choose their own city where he live then how i can show them 6 city who have name alma

Comment: I think then you can have a small popup and in it display 4-5 small map size widget asking user as to which location it is. Yahoo PlaceFinder returns a small static image of the location as well.